# How to implement recursive division in java

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, division, maze

I've been struggling to implement a working form of a recursive division algorithm in Java in order to randomly generate a maze. I'm trying to do this:

http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm

I don't want to copy paste code, but I just don't understand how I'm supposed to recursively divide the maze whilst creating holes in and not filling those holes in with new walls.

Honestly at this point I'm feeling a tad bit too embarrassed to post my current code, but i will if anyone wants to see it.

I would really like to see a code example where i can understand what's happening because everything else I have found is in Ruby, python or Javascript and built using poor variable names and nearly no comments. I can figure out the gist of what's happening, but it doesn't clear it up for me completely.

I keep getting walls right next to each other, or placed incorrectly so that they don't properly bisect the walls.

For further reference i am working in processing on a project.

```
  class Maze
{
  int[][] mazeTiles = new int[width/50][height/50];
  boolean completion;

  int HORIZONTAL = 0;
  int VERTICAL = 1;
  int slice;

  int xMin, xMax;
  int yMin, yMax;

  int xRand;
  int yRand;

  int distX,distY;
  int yPoint;



  int horizontalSize;
  int verticalSize;

  Maze()
  {
    completion = false;



    xMin = 0;
    yMin = 0;


    slice = 50;


    verticalSize = mazeTiles[0].length;
    horizontalSize = mazeTiles.length;

    xMax = horizontalSize;
    yMax = verticalSize;
  }

  void generateMaze()
  {
    divide(xMin, yMin, xMax, yMax);
    // need to variables based on horizontal or vertical
  }

  void drawMaze()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeTiles.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < mazeTiles[0].length; j++)
      {
        if (mazeTiles[i][j] == 0)
        {
          fill(255, 0, 0);
          rect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
          fill(0);
        } else if (mazeTiles[i][j] ==1)
        {
          fill(0, 255, 0);
          rect(i*50, j*50, 50, 50);
          fill(0);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void divide(int xStart, int yStart, int xEnd, int yEnd)
  {
      distX = xEnd - xStart;
      distY = yEnd - yStart;

      int yPoint = (int)random(4, yEnd-4);
      int xPoint = (int)random(4, xEnd-4);
    if(distX > distY)
    {
      slice = VERTICAL;
    }
    else if(distY > distX)
    {
      slice = HORIZONTAL;
    }

    else
    {
      slice = (int)random(HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL+1);
    }

    if (slice == HORIZONTAL)
    {      
      wall(slice, xStart, yPoint, xEnd, yEnd);
      if (distX >= 2 || distY >= 2)
      {
        println("HORIZONTAL");
        divide(xStart,yStart,xEnd,yEnd-yPoint); //Top  // yEnd - random y value chosen 
        divide(xStart,yStart+yPoint,xEnd,yEnd); //Bottom 
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      }
    }

    if (slice == VERTICAL)
    {
      wall(slice, xPoint, yStart, xEnd, yEnd);

      if (distX >= 2 || distY >= 2)
      {
        println("VERTICAL");
        divide(xStart+xPoint,yStart,xEnd,yEnd); //Right
        divide(xStart,yStart,xEnd - xPoint,yEnd); //Left
      }
      else
      {
        return;
      }
    }
  }



  void resetMaze()
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < mazeTiles.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < mazeTiles[0].length; j++)
      {
        mazeTiles[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }
  }


  void wall(int direction, int startX, int startY, int lenX, int lenY)
  {

    if (lenY >= 0 && lenX >= 0 && lenX <= horizontalSize && lenY <= verticalSize && startX >= 0 && startY >= 0 && startX < horizontalSize && startY < verticalSize)
    {
      if (direction == HORIZONTAL)
      {
        for (int i = startX; i < lenX; i++)
        {
          int j = startY;
          mazeTiles[i][j] = 1;
        }

        cutHole((int)random(startX+1, lenX-1), startY, mazeTiles);
      }

      if (direction == VERTICAL)
      {
        for (int i = startY; i < lenY; i++)
        {
          int j = startX;
          mazeTiles[j][i] = 1;
        }
        cutHole(startX, (int)random(startY+1, lenY-1), mazeTiles);
      }
    }
  }

  void cutHole(int xLoc, int yLoc, int[][] grid)
  {
    grid[xLoc-1][yLoc-1] = 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post your code. This is stack overflow after all.

Comment: If you don't want help with your code, what is it you want?

Comment: Post a [mcve] of the part of your code where you are having a problem. Describe clearly what you expected to happen, and what actually happened, including any error messages that you get.

Comment: To add to @shmosel's comment, your title asked for "recursive division".  Division is repeated subtraction from a mathematical perspective, and is incredibly simple to accomplish.  However in your question, you make reference to a maze and how you go about dividing up the maze in some way.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to do something like this: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm

Comment: @MattTimmermans yeah, exactly, I've looked at it, but for some reason mentally I can't figure out how I'm supposed to translate it into Java and processing. I'm probably just an idiot i guess..

Comment: Well, unfortunately that makes it pretty hard for anyone to figure out how to help you, because Jamis Buck's page is really excellently written.

Comment: @shmosel  You're right i should post code, i did. Honestly mentally I'm having a bit of a rough moment right now and I felt too self-conscious to initially post it, I'm sorry about that.  I more so want a Java example of http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm, which makes it seem like i just want to copy it, but that's not the case. I just don't know what that example transfers to java. I look at the code and keep saying "Can i do that in Java?" Maybe... "Can i do that in processing?" Probably not... How could I? UGH.

Comment: @MattTimmermans I'm aware it's well written. I'm saying i don't know how to translate his example to Java. That's it. Half the stuff in his code is stuff I can't do in processing.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt posted code. NO errors, it just doesn't do this : http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm.    Rather it makes walls randomly and sporadically.

Comment: Guys, please help. i can't do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant recursive Ruby code at [your link](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2011/1/12/maze-generation-recursive-division-algorithm) in Java is:

```
private static final int HORIZONTAL = 1;
private static final int VERTICAL = 2;

private static final int S = 1;
private static final int E = 2;

private Random rand = new Random();

private void divide(int[][] grid, int x, int y, int width, int height, int orientation) {
    if(width < 2 || height < 2) {
        return;
    }
    boolean horizontal = orientation == HORIZONTAL;

    int wx = x + (horizontal ? 0 : rand.nextInt(width - 2));
    int wy = y + (horizontal ? rand.nextInt(height - 2) : 0);

    int px = wx + (horizontal ? rand.nextInt(width) : 0);
    int py = wy + (horizontal ? 0 : rand.nextInt(height));

    int dx = horizontal ? 1 : 0;
    int dy = horizontal ? 0 : 1;

    int length = horizontal ? width : height;

    int dir = horizontal ? S : E;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(wx != px || wy != py) {
            grid[wy][wx] |= dir;
        }
        wx += dx;
        wy += dy;
    }

    int nx = x;
    int ny = y;
    int w = horizontal ? width : wx - x + 1;
    int h = horizontal ? wy - y + 1 : height;
    divide(grid, nx, ny, w, h, chooseOrientation(w, h));

    nx = horizontal ? x : wx + 1;
    ny = horizontal ? wy + 1 : y;
    w = horizontal ? width : x + width - wx - 1;
    h = horizontal ? y + height - wy - 1 : height;
    divide(grid, nx, ny, w, h, chooseOrientation(w, h));
} 

private int chooseOrientation(int w, int h) {
    if(w < h) {
        return HORIZONTAL;
    } else if (h < w) {
        return VERTICAL;
    } else {
        return rand.nextInt(2) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, even though i didn't see this until it was pretty much too late for me i really appreciate it. 
This is so much more understandable to me now I can pretty much see where i was making mistakes. I also didn't know what ternary operators were until after this so I certainly learned a lot. I was over complicating everything too much. THANK YOU SO MUCH SIR.